# window.print doesn't execute more than once

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

```
function prompter() {
    var NoS = prompt("Enter How many Stamp Papers Do you want?", "1");

    for (i = 0; i < NoS; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            document.getElementById('sno').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('sno').value) + 1;
        }
        //window.print();
        //var printwindow=window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1000,height=780,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        window.print();
        //var printdata=document.getElementById('printarea').innerHTML;

        //printwindow.document.write();                      
        //printwindow.document.close();
        //window.focus();

        //window.close(); 
    }
    window.history.go(-1);
}
```

It is working with ECLIPSE IDE browser, but it is not working with external browsers, it is printing only once.

Comment: One problem is `NoS` is a string and you are treating it as a number.

Comment: @epascarello: Indeed. It'll work in the above, but it's not something one likes to rely on.

Comment: Try pressing `CTRL P` several times. Only 1 print dialog will open.

Answer (score 1):

You have no control of (or view into) the printing process in any cross-browser fashion. `window.print` just starts the process, typically opening a dialog box the user interacts with. I'm not surprised calling it repeatedly doesn't have the desired result.

I don't think you can do what you want to do. If you need to offer them something different for each copy (the `sno` value), you'll have to have them print one, click a button to get the next, print that, click a button to get the next, etc.

Or alternately, output all of the ones they want to a window they print just once, but pagination becomes tricky. :-)

Comment: @RameshJn: See the second paragraph above.

Comment: k., I have another scenario to print a page multiple times., here sno not needed.. Can you suggest...

Comment: @RameshJn: No, I can't. As I said, there's no cross-browser view of the printing process. If you can't know when it finishes, you can't know that it's time to start the next print. If the browser offers the user a number of copies option, they can use that, otherwise they'll just have to print more than once. Attempting to control the printing process from the page just isn't feasible at the moment.

Comment: I did with for loop repetation in jsp, and print once.. i am getting the results.. thank you all.